# div right aligned dont keep at top

Tags: html, css

How can I keep my red box on top line when the center div has a very wide content?
When The centered div has much content, the red div goes to another line.
Do you know why this occurs?

Take a look at my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5dC6T/3/

Comment: Can you clarify? From what I can see, no matter how much content is in the central div, the bright red box to the right stays anchored to the top of the container. So what's the issue?

Comment: @Utkanos try resizing the window; the content falls below the container.

Comment: When I resize the browser smaller, the bright red box on the right drops below the text. Is that what you want to prevent?

Comment: Utkanos, you are right. This is the problem. Actually, I want a 3 column structure with left and right with fixed width and center should expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the way that you've ordered your `<div>` elements. Try:

```
<div>
    <div class="red-box"></div>
    <img class="photo" alt="" />
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>Data</span>
    <span>City</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* These two will stay anchored on the right and left */
.red-box { float: right; }
img.photo { float: left; }
```

I've made these modifications to your current code: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/38qYS/

Comment: Very good. Why this occur? I achieved what I want removing the float left from the center column and changing the order.

Comment: Floats allow content to wrap around them, but this will only happen if the floated element appears above the other elements in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
#QuadroEvento div.TopoEvento div.euvou{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}​
```

The key being: `position: absolute;`

You can also use `position: fixed;` etc.,  see here for more details: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp